# Refresh leaflet map in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I want to refresh circles of leaflet map after zoom:

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  Map as LeafletMap,
  TileLayer,
  Marker,
  Circle,
  Tooltip,
  Popup
} from "react-leaflet";

import MarkerClusterGroup from "react-leaflet-markercluster";
import data from "./data.json";

const TILE_LAYER_ATTRIBUTION =
  "Map tiles by Carto, under CC BY 3.0. Data by OpenStreetMap, under ODbL";
const TILE_LAYER_URL =
  "https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";

export function Map() {
  const position = [55.2854062,23.9327383];
  const initialZoom = 8;
  let showTooltip = false;
  let mapRef = React.createRef();

  const renderMarkers = () => {
    showTooltip = mapRef && mapRef.viewport && mapRef.viewport.zoom > 8 ? true : false;
    let circles = [];
    circles = data.map(item => (
      <Circle key={item.id}
        center={[item.latitude, item.longitude]}
        color="red"
        fillColor="red"
        radius={100}
      >
        <Tooltip className="circle-tooltip" permanent={true} direction={"center"}>
        {showTooltip ? <span>1</span> : <span></span>
      }
        </Tooltip>
        <Popup>
          <p>
            {item.address}, {item.city}
          </p>
          <p>{item.time}</p>
        </Popup>
      </Circle>
    ));

    return circles;
  };


  return (
    <LeafletMap ref={(ref) => { mapRef = ref }} center={position} zoom={initialZoom} onzoomend={() => renderMarkers() }>
      <TileLayer attribution={TILE_LAYER_ATTRIBUTION} url={TILE_LAYER_URL} />
      {
        <MarkerClusterGroup showCoverageOnHover={false}>
          {renderMarkers()}
        </MarkerClusterGroup>
      }
    </LeafletMap>
  );
}
```

however they are not being redrawn after the function renderMarkers() is called. What could be wrong here?

Comment: where is `data` variable ?

Comment: it comes from json file, updated

Comment: I ran your example and seems to work. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: That at first <span></span> is rendered in CIrcle (which is fine) but after zoomin in closer <span>1</span> with 1 inside should be shown. But after onzoomend map circles aren't redrawn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`showTooltip` should be a state variable using `useState` so when it changes component will rerender.

Moreover I think if you use functional components it should be `useRef` instead of createRef() and then

```
<LeafletMap
      ref={mapRef}
...
```

So it should be like this:

```
  let [showTooltip, setShowTooltip] = React.useState(false);
  let mapRef = React.useRef();

  const renderMarkers = () => {
    const map = mapRef.current;

    if (map) {
      console.log(map.leafletElement.getZoom());
      // change here the showTooltip flag
      setShowTooltip(map.leafletElement.getZoom() > 13 ? true : false);
    }
  };



<MarkerClusterGroup showCoverageOnHover={false}>
          {data.map(item => (
            <Circle
 ....
<MarkerClusterGroup/>
```

I changed slightly the example to have zoom bigger than 13 to show 1 and smaller not to show it to be able to demonstrate on the demo because in smaller zoom levels the bubble is displayed and you won't be able to see the tooltip.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/refresh-leaflet-map-in-react-when-onzoomend-xp26l)